# What is the size of a RSA signature in bytes?

Tags: rsa, crypto++

I'm currently using Crypto++ to generate a signature for a block of data. I expected the signature to be 20 bytes ( SHA 1 Hash) , as my understanding was that the signature is just an encrypted hash. But when checking with maxsignaturelength and signature length , it seems that it is 192 bytes. Is it normal?

Comment: A better answer is available at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658728/rsa-signature-size

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The size of the signature is the size of the RSA modulus in bytes.