# Python: Encrypt using existing public key

Tags: python, encryption, pycrypto

I have a public key that looks like this:

BgIAAACkAABSU0ExAAQAAAEAAQCH3cm40A7P6GzlRrDMC1hEgB9kwPYLCei0z/NxnEwzj/brpcmhMXoebyW7GLoAgNaVigi5/+UMbuXwva9e6WpAZu+45a+wAuBJGetnlhfhgGWs8WpaE6qYpB94m3UUWdAB5rwSvC4gxHzHcGCk5M3ilNxA5Hk3jcXcvwzum+fHqg==

How do I encrypt a string with that key using Python?

I have been trying varyations on this:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
rsakey = RSA.importKey(key)
```

But I keep getting the error **ValueError: RSA key format is not supported**

Comment: Where did you get this key and are you sure it's an RSA key?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print a public key as string and encrypt with it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777428/how-to-print-a-public-key-as-string-and-encrypt-with-it)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read a RSA public key in PEM + PKCS#1 format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569189/how-to-read-a-rsa-public-key-in-pem-pkcs1-format)

Comment: Looks like some kind of Windows RSA key blob.

Comment: As far as I know, it's an RSA key. I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569189/how-to-read-a-rsa-public-key-in-pem-pkcs1-format before posting this question. It also did not work for me. It returned "ValueError: Not a DER SEQUENCE.".

Comment: It seems to be a RSA public key generated with `ssh-keygen`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following as the input instead:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
BgIAAACkAABSU0ExAAQAAAEAAQCH3cm40A7P6GzlRrDMC1hEgB9kwPYLCei0z/NxnEwzj/brpcmhMXoebyW7GLoAgNaVigi5/+UMbuXwva9e6WpAZu+45a+wAuBJGetnlhfhgGWs8WpaE6qYpB94m3UUWdAB5rwSvC4gxHzHcGCk5M3ilNxA5Hk3jcXcvwzum+fHqg==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```