# Is it normal for an RSA digital signature to be 512 bytes?

Tags: java

I wrote my own implementation of the RSA digital signature. I use SHA-512 hashing. I sign the picture in png format. At the output, I get a signature of 512 bytes, is this normal or a bug?

It turns out that it is due to the fact that our hash has a length of 64 bytes, the maximum number generated by me can have a weight of 8 bytes, it turns out 1 byte of the file = 8 bytes of digital signature. The hashToInt function represents an array of bytes as an array of ints (add 256 to negative bytes). Made to adequately perform the ModPow operation

```
Random random = new Random();

    byte[] byteArray = new byte[8];

    MessageDigest sha512 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
    byte[] array = Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects\\CryptoLab1\\src\\crypto\\dino.png"));
    byte[] hash = sha512.digest(array);
    var hashInt = hashToIntArray(hash);

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects\\CryptoLab1\\src\\crypto\\DigitalSignatureRSA.png");

    BigInteger P = BigInteger.probablePrime(32, random);
    BigInteger Q = BigInteger.probablePrime(32, random);

    BigInteger N = P.multiply(Q);
    BigInteger f = (P.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).multiply(Q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));

    BigInteger d;
    BigInteger c;
    BigInteger signature;
    BigInteger checkSignature;

    do {
        d = new BigInteger(32, random);
    } while (!(d.gcd(f).equals(BigInteger.ONE)) && d.compareTo(f) < 0);


    c = d.modInverse(f);

    List<BigInteger> digitalSignature = new ArrayList<>();
    List<BigInteger> deDigitalSignature = new ArrayList<>();
    List<byte[]> byteList = new ArrayList<>();

    //create a digital signature
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
        BigInteger y = BigInteger.valueOf(hashInt[i]);

        signature = cryptoLab1.ModPow(y, c, N);
        digitalSignature.add(signature);
        byteArray = toHH(signature); //toHH - representation of a number in 8 byte format
        byteList.add(byteArray);

        out.write(byteList.get(i));
    }

    // numeric signature verification

    var fileData = Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects\\CryptoLab1\\src\\crypto\\dino.png"));
    var hashFileData = hashToIntArray(sha512.digest(fileData));

    for (int i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {

        checkSignature = cryptoLab1.ModPow(digitalSignature.get(i), d, N);
        deDigitalSignature.add(checkSignature);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
        if(BigInteger.valueOf(hashFileData[i]).equals(deDigitalSignature.get(i))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: You might want to look at other questions like https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3505/what-is-the-length-of-an-rsa-signature and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658728/rsa-signature-size

Comment: *I wrote my own implementation of the RSA digital signature.* Why?

Comment: Homework at the university. Have I implemented the RSA digital signature correctly?

Comment: I can't tell you but there's one easy way to find out: just run a sha512 utility and compare your results ;)